# How hidden Links in Dashboard page to ROLE ADMIN and show it to ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN?

Tags: php, symfony

I have install SonataAdminBundle and configure it manage my Entities, 
however I have 2 Admin Roles : ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN and I 
want to limit access to some Admin services for ROLE_ADMIN, 
I'm using this in security.yml file :

```
access_control: 
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
        - { path: ^/admin/ads, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN } 
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } 
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

it's work perfectly, when a user with ROLE_ADMIN click on manage Ads 
link, he will be in Access denied page, but I want to hidden this link in menu 
in top Nav and in Dashboard page, how I do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default security handler of the SonataAdminBundle is the NOOP implementation, which is always returns true. You have to [change the security configuration](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) of the admin bundle.

With the role based security handler you have to add roles to the security.yml config [as described here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html#integrating-the-bundle-into-the-sonata-admin-bundle). For every admin class there is number of role you have to add to your base role in the role hierarchy. If you have an admin class with the id `my_bundle.admin.object` and`my_bundle.admin.protected_object`:

```
security:
  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: 
      - ROLE_USER
      - ROLE_ADMIN
      - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
      - ROLE_MY_BUNDLE_ADMIN_PROTECTED_OBJECT_LIST
      - ROLE_MY_BUNDLE_ADMIN_PROTECTED_OBJECT_EDIT
      ....
    ROLE_ADMIN:
      - ROLE_USER
      - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_EDIT
      - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST
      - ROLE_MY_BUNDLE_ADMIN_OBJECT_LIST
      - ROLE_MY_BUNDLE_ADMIN_OBJECT_EDIT
      ...
```

You might have to enumerate all admin/action combination as roles. Maybe implementing a custom security handler based on the [RoleSecurityHandler](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Security/Handler/RoleSecurityHandler.php) is a better choice if you have large number of admin classes.

*Note* I don't know too much about ACLs in symfony, neither the AclSecurityHandler.

Answer (score 0):

in your template, do something like:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <li><a href="{{ path('zayso_natgames_admin') }}">Admin</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

If these templates are in the Sonata bundle then you will need to override them in your app directory.